# Compare 2 columns in 2 workbooks, copy matched row if match is found

Tags: vba, excel

I have two workbooks (or 2 sheets): Workbook A and Workbook B.
I want to compare:
Columns B and C in Workbook A **WITH**
Columns A and B in Workbook B
If a Match is found THEN
I need to copy the MATCHED row from Workbook B and paste it onto the MATCHED row on workbook A. 
In other words: I need to copy the cell values of Columns C and D of the matched row of Workbook B onto cells of columns D and E of matched row in Workbook A.

What I have so far *only* compares the 2 columns which I'm hoping is correct.
The code below is for 2 sheets instead of two workbooks:

```
Sub compareNcopy()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1"): Set sh2 = Sheets(2): Set sh3 = Sheets(3)


Dim i As Long, j As Long,
Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long
Dim nxtRow As Long
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range

lr1 = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lr2 = sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lr1
    Set rng1 = sh1.Range("A" & i)

    For j = 1 To lr2
        Set rng2 = sh2.Range("A" & j)

        If StrComp(CStr(rng1.Value), CStr(rng2.Value), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

            If rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value = rng2.Offset(0, 1).Value Then

            End If

        End If
        Set rng2 = Nothing
    Next j
    Set rng1 = Nothing
Next i
End Sub
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy between 2 sheets (or even two books) is pretty much the same as if you were copying to another cell in the same sheet (or book), you just have to specify which sheet (or book). What you would want to do is something along the lines of:

```
sh2.Cells(j,3).Resize(1,2).Copy Destination:=sh1.Cells(i,3).Resize(1,2)
```

This is for if the data you want to copy is found in `sh2`. If it is the other way around, switch the `sh2` and `sh1`, and the `j` and `i`.

If you want to copy between workbooks, you will need to add `Workbooks(wb1).` in front of the `Sheets(sh2).` specifier, with `wb1` being the workbook variable.

EDIT: Since `sh2` in essence is `Sheets(2)` what I had previously shown was `Sheets(Sheets(2))` which makes no sense and that is why the error was popping up. My apologies. Instead of using `Sheets(sh2)` just use `sh2`, and the same goes for `sh1`. I have fixed the above code to reflect this.

Comment: Thank for the response. I added the line you suggested but it is giving me a "Mismatch Run-Time Error:13" any ideas as to why? I changed the code to compare the columns as: 
    Sheets(sh2).Cells(j, 3).Resize(1, 2).Copy Destination:=Sheets(sh1).Cells(i, 4).Resize(1, 2)

Comment: @user3720702 It is now fixed, sorry about that.